# SuiteCRM - Record Delete permission based on created by field

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I just need to give delete permission to the user if record created by login user in SutieCRM. I have checked it there was Owner option exist in permission chart. But it's working based on assigned to field. but I want to give delete permission based on created by field.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: create logic hook or use some other logic to copy Create by into Assigned to. Moreover disable editing of assigned to field.

Answer (score 0):

In view.list.php and view.details.php you can check for :-

```
if($GLOBALS['current_user'] !== $bean->created_by){
       $("delete_button").disabled
}
```

This is just the basic code, you will need to tweek it according to your needs.